# Logistics of Developing Contracts

Tags: smart-contract, plutus, contracts, gougen, plutus-playground

We've done a lot of development on the Plutus Playground; in what ways will the logistics of developing and deploying contracts differ in Gougen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the techniques you have learned for development on the Playground (or using the `EmulatorTrace`-monad) will still be valuable and relevant for Goguen.

The only difference is that with Goguen, you will *additionally* write a UI for your contract(s).

But you still need to write on- and off-chain contracts and test them on the Playground or in the `EmulatorTrace`-monad.